# Can't send data to socket (server) in assembly language (x86_64) on linux

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to send a data to a server using assembly language. In python everything works. Now I want to do that in asm.
The server is local (127.0.0.1) on port 4096.

```
section .bss
        sock_fd: resb 4
section .data
        msg: db "Hello World",0
        len equ $ - msg
        struct: dw 2
                db 10h, 00h
                db 7fh, 0, 0, 1
                db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0


section .text
global socket
socket:
        mov rax, 41
        mov rdi, 2
        mov rsi, 1
        syscall
    mov [sock_fd], rax
connect:
    mov rax, 42
    mov rdi, [sock_fd]
    mov rsi, struct
    mov rdx, 1024
    syscall
sendto:
        mov rdi, [sock_fd]
        mov rax, 44
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, len
        mov r8, struct
        mov r9, 16
        syscall
exit:
        mov rax, 60
        syscall
```

I am trying to send a data to a server using assembly language. In python everything works. Now I want to do that in asm.
The server is local (127.0.0.1) on port 4096.

Comment: Did you try running this under strace?  It's weird that you're setting the 5th and 6th args to syscall (r8 and r9) but not the 4th arg (r10 taking the place of rcx in the x86-64 SysV function-calling convention because `syscall` steps on it.)  `sendto` takes 6 args, the 4th being `int flags`.

Comment: When I run this, `socket()` works and returns fd=3.  But `connect()` fails with `-EINVAL`, not ECONNREFUSED (which I'd expect on my machine with no listener on that port, if the connect call was working): `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4096), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 1024) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`.  So sendto fails with EPIPE.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the 3rd arg to `connect` is passing 1024 as the length of the `const struct sockaddr *addr` 2nd arg, which is obviously way too big for a `struct sockaddr`.  (`strace nc localhost 80` shows it trying to connect with size=16 for a struct holding an IPv4 address).  Near duplicate of [Why is the address length parameter neccessary when binding a socket in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41240492)

Comment: @PeterCordes
44 (rax) int (rdi) void * (rsi) size_t (rdx) unsigned (r10) struct sockaddr * (r8) int (r9)

That's according to the documentation

Comment: Yes, exactly.  As https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendto.2.html shows, that 4th arg (in R10) is `int flags`.  Whatever documentation you're looking at that says `unsigned` doesn't match the `int flags` in the Linux man page but close enough.  Regardless, `r10d` should be set to some value, or zeroed if you don't want to pass any flags.  Don't leave garbage in it.  (In `_start` in a static executable, it will happen to be zero.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have zeroed that but still not works...

Comment: Right, it won't work unless you also fix the length arg for `connect`, like I said in my 3rd comment. That's why `connect` returns `-EINVAL`.  The bug of not setting `r10d` before `sendto` is separate and happens not to be a problem because `r10` is already zeroed.  It's just the first thing I noticed so I commented about it first.